# how to select LED protection device?

Tags: led, protection

I have this simple LED configuration:

[image]

Voltage source is 24VDC so with the 1k resistor and three 2V LED, current is around 20mA.

I want to put a PLED device across each LED. how do I select correct part number?

PLED link is here:

[https://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/led_protectors/littelfuse_led_protector_automotive_pled_unidirectional_pledxux_a_datasheet.pdf.pdf](https://www.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/led_protectors/littelfuse_led_protector_automotive_pled_unidirectional_pledxux_a_datasheet.pdf.pdf)

Comment: I don't think you can select one of those: *"Compatible with one, two and three watt LEDs that have a nominal 3V forward characteristic."* 20 mA and (assuming) 3 V is 60 mW. Not even close to 1 W. Also, did you look at their "LED Driver" circuit for the LED string in the test circuit? Do you imagine that is a voltage source? Or a current source?

Comment: These things are designed for larger LEDs with a constant-current driver. Why not just use 3x resistors, a bit more wasted power but more reliable?

Comment: You don’t need to protect LEDs except during handling. However you do need to use a power supply closer to >6V for 3LEDs rather than waste 18/24= 3/4 of power in resisters

Comment: 24VDC source is required. In one module, there will be 50 groups of this 1xresistor/3xLED setup.

Comment: If you use as source current stabilizator, not just resistor, using those devices possible. Overvise current will increase for rest LfEDs each time when device activated.

Comment: If you have a resistor in series with the LEDs, which you appear to, one great way to protect them is to use a fusible or film resistor with barely enough wattage rating.  Thin film resistors aren't rated as fusible, but they tend to burn out open and you're protecting LEDs, not Faberge eggs.  If the LEDs go overcurrent, the resistor burns out and you have to replace a whole bunch of penny resistors instead of trying to find exact matches for existing LEDs.

Answer (score 0):

finally got an answer from Littelfuse so ended up using PLED6UQ12 for each LED.